# TFS Query Error - SQL Server encountered error 0x80070005

Tags: sql-server, tfs

Users are receiving the following error after running a query in TFS.

> Error:  SQL Server encountered error 0x80070005 while communicating with full-text filter daemon host (FDHost) process. Make sure that the FDHost process is running. To re-start the FDHost process, run the sp_fulltext_service 'restart_all_fdhosts' command or restart the SQL Server instance.

FDHost is running and has been restarted.  Same error after running a query.

How would I resolve this error?

Comment: Suggest you also check  the **Event View** on TFS server, if there are some more detail error info. Which may help to narrow down this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the service wasn't start.  The SQL Admin started the service but a new error appeared.

Error:  An error has occurred during the full-text query. Common causes include: word-breaking errors or timeout, FDHOST permissions/ACL issues, service account missing privileges, malfunctioning IFilters, communication channel issues with FDHost and sqlservr.exe, etc.

This https://www.codykonior.com/2017/04/26/something-you-didnt-know-about-validating-full-text-indexing/ helped resolve the new error and the query completed successfully.